# WCF Rest for handling Retrofit send data

Tags: java, android, json, wcf, retrofit

I want to send some data with retrofit including an image and three strings,
how should my WCF server side method signature be to handle these posted data if someone could help me?

The below code is my client side with retrofit(although im not sure it is well written).

```
        @Multipart
        @POST("PostBanderolDataJSON")
        Call<MyResponse> PostData(@Part("banderolNr") RequestBody banderolNr, @Part("pharmacy") RequestBody pharmacy, @Part("place") RequestBody place, @Part("report_pic\"; filename=\"rp.png\" ") RequestBody file);
    }

 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(RetrofitApiInterface.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            RetrofitApiInterface api = retrofit.create(RetrofitApiInterface.class);

            RequestBody reportImage = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), ImagePath);
            RequestBody banderoNr = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), etBanderolNr.getText().toString());
            RequestBody pharmacy = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), Pharmacy.getText().toString());
            RequestBody place = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), Place.getText().toString());

            Call<MyResponse> call = api.PostData(banderoNr,pharmacy,place,reportImage);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (!response.body().error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Sent Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error occurred...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        progress.dismiss();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong with the request to the server !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<MyResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    progress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: What did you try, where are you stuck? Can you send and receive a single text?

Comment: The question was clear, what should the wcf method signature be to get the data that was send above, cuz im new in web services

Comment: Your question is clear. If you want an answer based on your current question, you need to hire a software developer. If on the other hand you want *help to solve your problem yourself* you are on the right track here, but you need to show your best effort. You need to show what you tried and where your problem is. Because "I cannot do it, please do it for me" is not asking for help... it's asking for a freebie. And we don't do that here.

Comment: I have just asked how the signature of the method in WCF should be, dont play the smart guy here, if youre here to help someone and cant help this is not the place for you, we do not cook here, and it is not the place for advices, give your help or if you cant dont waste your letters. Go somewhere else

Comment: I'm just trying to help you get your question into a shape that it will be answered. If you don't want to spend the energy to do so, that's ok, just don't get your hope's too high on getting an answer.